# Scala value class, use cases

Tags: scala, value-class

I know `value class` in scala inline the operation at compiler time.

maybe like this

```
case class A(i: Int) extends AnyVal {
   def +(that: A) = A(this.i + that.i)
} 
A(1) + A(2) // After compile it equals to 1 + 2
```

But It seems not a big deal to me.

It might enhance performance but,

calling `this.i + that.i` does not seems that much slower than `i + i`

Why we need `value class` in scala and any use cases???

Comment: *calling this.i + that.i does not seems that much slower than i + i* How did you determine this? Did you microbenchmark that code?

Comment: Besides of the fact the call is faster (which will be most likely inlined by the JIT compiler anyway), value classes avoid object instantiation, therefore reducing Garbage Collection load.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Why would you wrap a single value into an additional class?**

One big use case is type safety. Let's say you have function that can multiply money, like so:

```
def multiply(factor: Int, amount: Int): Int = ???
```

The problem with this is that it would be very easy to confuse the two arguments and therefore call the function incorrectly. With values classes, you could create a `Money` type and re-write the function like so:

```
case class Money(amount: Int) extends AnyVal
def multiply(factor: Int, amount: Money): Money = ???
```

Now with your special `Money` type, the compiler will tell you if you try to pass arguments in the wrong order.

Were it not a value class, people may say that the added type safety is not worth the performance penalty in some cases. However with value classes, you have no runtime overhead (there are limitations though: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

An alternative to achieve the same goal are unboxed (no runtime overhead) tagged types in scalaz: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tagged+type.html

Note that for example haskell uses `newtype` for the same idea: https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11):

Let's look at how Scala works with value classes (`-print` option).

```
case class A(i: Int) extends AnyVal {
   def +(that: A) = A(this.i + that.i)
} 
A(1) + A(2)
```

is translated to:

```
final def +$extension($this: Int, that: Int): Int = $this.+(that)
...
A.+$extension(1, 2)
```

As you can see Scala avoids working with class `A` and simply adds `Int` to `Int` returning `Int`. At the same time:

```
case class A(i: Int) {
   def +(that: A) = A(this.i + that.i)
} 
A(1) + A(2)
```

is translated to:

```
def +(that: A): A = new A(this.i().+(that.i()))
...
new A(1).+(new A(2))
```

So to compute `1 + 2` you need to instantiate class `A` three times.

Comment: what a great explanation! thank you for your detail. performance cost of not using value class seems obvious

Answer (score 1):

> Value classes are a mechanism in Scala to avoid allocating runtime objects. This is accomplished through the definition of new AnyVal subclasses.

More about value classes is here [Value Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html)